# Spring MVC and Angular Json Req mismatch

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, jetty

So the issue I am seeing here is that I have made some changes to the RequestBody POJO but when I debug I still see the Object being created with the old data . I think there is some kind of caching going on which is causing this mismatch but not sure how to fix it . Let me clarify what I ams saying by the pic below

[image]

as you can see I changed address to phone and username to name but the object is looking for username and address and not populating the value . To give a little more context here is the where the debug pointer is

[image]

I am running this on jetty anyone has any clue on how to resolve this.

Comment: Delete the target folder and try again

Comment: I forgot to specify that it is a gradle project. Tried gradle clean and gradle eclipse but did not work

Comment: Sometime gradle is unable to delete all file. You can manually delete file and then try again. Also you can close the project, remove all build file and then re-import the project.

Comment: didn't do the trick

Answer (score 0):

So found my answer after digging for a while. The getter and setter for the variables in POJO should match the name of the variable being passed in .

In above example when I renmaed variable userName to name I did not rename the gettter and setter from

```
getUserName -> getName
setUserName ->  setName
```

so lesson from this when modifiyng POJO make certain the getter and setter match the req json variabe being sent in by the POST req.